# all_simple_paths in networkx is taking too long to run

Tags: python, graph, networkx, recommendation-engine

I am trying to get all possible paths between two nodes through networkx using 'all_simple_paths' function. Here are my graph details:

```
Name: 
Type: MultiGraph
Number of nodes: 2416
Number of edges: 59822
Average degree:  49.5215
```

Here is the code:

`nx.all_simple_paths(G_3, source=gp2, target=gp1, cutoff=5)`

I am doing this movielens 100k dataset. Please let me know any workaround for the same. As I keep increasing the graph, it takes exponentially longer than ever. I could only run it for 20 nodes and 100 edges in a 64gb linux m/c.

Comment: Please format your code properly. I have submitted an edit.

Comment: You may need to think about whether there is something else that could give you the same information.  I expect a large number of paths.